# C Why is sizeof('a')=4 and sizeof(char)=1?

Tags: c, size, byte

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    printf("size of tab = %d\n", sizeof('\t'));
    printf("size of a = %d\n", sizeof('a'));
    printf("size of char = %d\n", sizeof(char));
}
```

Output:

```
size of tab = 4
size of a = 4
size of char = 1
```

Why is the size of `'a'` and the size of `char` different. Isn't `'a'` a `char`?

Comment: `sizeof('\t')` is actually calculating the size of an `int` where `int` is the ASCII value of `'\t'` and similar is the case for `sizeof('a')`

Comment: `'a'` is an `int`.  All constants in C are at least `int`.

Comment: 6.4.4.4 Character constants p2 _An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed
in single-quotes, as in 'x'._ and p10 _An integer character constant has type int._ 6.5.3.4 The sizeof ... operators p4 _When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or
signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1._

Answer (score 1):

`'a` is the int containing the character `a`.
take a look at the values of these expressions:

```
sizeof((char) 'a');
char a = 'a';
sizeof(a);
```